# Recyclerview height not change after changing the data in it

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working with `recyclerview` having `webviews` in it. `Recyclerview` height is wrap_content. It works fine. But when I am setting a new adapter with new data, data is loading but `recyclerview` height not effected. It is of the same height as of previous. I want to change the height of `recyclerview` as of the data. I have also tried it with measuring the height of child content and set it to the `recyclerview` but doesn't find anything relevant. If anyone know how to change it do let me know.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Please read up here on how to ask perfect question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, Better is post your code snippet for view and setup recyclerview

Answer (score 1):

Use `recyclerView.invalidate();` after the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method or after setting new data.

Comment: Already tried with recyclerView.invalidate() but not working. Actually I have to set adapter again. notifyDataSetChanged() will not work in my case.

Answer (score -1):

For example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/images"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        >
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
 </Relativelayout>
```

Change LayoutParams in the code.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp =
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 500);
 recyclerView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```